# I am unable to find $_GET PARAMS LIKE ?a=abc IN PHP WHILE USING PHP

Tags: php, string, url, get

I am unable to find `$_GET` params like `?a=abc` in PHP

```
http://www.example.com/jobs/user/profile/abc-xyz?a=abc&x=y&p=0
```

Now,

```
print_r($_REQUEST, 1);
```

gives me result

```
Array
(
    [url] => user/profile/abc-xyz
    [__utma] => 111872281.1951078106.1388050852.1388050852.1388050852.1
    [__utmz] => 111872281.1388050852.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
    [PHPSESSID] => 73n7sqdt4bct36da726dp3vjq7
)
```

and .. `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`
give me

```
url=user/profile/abc-xyz
```

I need to GET `$_GET['a']`
output shoud be `abc` etc

Comment: Your PHP may be configured REQUEST not to catch GET variables ..
But with $_GET['a'] it should be working..

Comment: Also did you check if your url re-write rule is supporting %{QUERY_STRING} ?

Comment: its should give me $_get['a'] value but for some reason its not working unable to find the problem but in ither poorjects its workign fine

Comment: @xrock check your php.ini for variables order and request order here is more info..
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a rewrite like this:

```
rewrite ^ http://example.com/jobs/(.*) jobs/index.php?url=$1
```

you need to add the args, like

```
rewrite ^ http://example.com/jobs/(.*) jobs/index.php?url=$1&$args
```

Comment: Thanks that solve with the change of 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
To 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php [PT,L]
Thanks

Comment: sorry for late reply i just open stack over flow right now. yes i accept this answer

Comment: Thx! I meant, clicking on the "accept" icon on the left (right underneath the voting arrows)

Comment: done ia hev one more question should i post another question or do i ask here?

Comment: Yes, ask a new question with the new context

Comment: Thanks here what i have asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256404/how-can-i-get-the-post-data-url-on-my-server-in-php

Comment: Ohh god thank you very much but my problem solved my seeing comment of the rewrite rule.RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L] To RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php [PT,L] T

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
print_r($_GET, 1)
```

To get $_GET variables...
So `$_GET['a']` should give you the desired result.

Comment: jobs/user/profile/xe-rock?a=abc&c=9
Array
(
    [url] => user/profile/Ahmed-Anees
it give me above resultnot GET parms
)

Comment: I don't know what you mean?